# How to add Contact Form 7 shortcode in Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contact-form-7, contact-form

In Contact Form 7 I have created a dropdown with 3 options under it "dallas" "houston" "austin" . I wrote this js code so that if I select Dallas then "houston" "austin" will hide. The rest of the options will work in the same way. But I am not able to insert the dropdown's shotcode

Here is the shotcode of my dropdown:- **[condition]**

I create this

```
    <div id="dallas"><h1>Dallas city</h1></div>
    <div id="houston"><h1>Houston City</h1></div>
    <div id="austin"><h1>Austin City</h1></div>


    <script>
        const paragraphText = "dallas"; 

const dallasDiv = document.getElementById("dallas");
const houstonDiv = document.getElementById("houston");
const austinDiv = document.getElementById("austin");

if (paragraphText === "dallas") {
  dallasDiv.style.display = "block";
  houstonDiv.style.display = "none";
  austinDiv.style.display = "none";
  sanantonioDiv.style.display = "none";
  atlantaDiv.style.display = "none";
} else if (paragraphText === "houston") {
  dallasDiv.style.display = "none";
  houstonDiv.style.display = "block";
  austinDiv.style.display = "none";
  sanantonioDiv.style.display = "none";
  atlantaDiv.style.display = "none";
} else if (paragraphText === "austin"){
  dallasDiv.style.display = "none";
  houstonDiv.style.display = "none";
  austinDiv.style.display = "block";
  sanantonioDiv.style.display = "none";
  atlantaDiv.style.display = "none";
} 

    </script>
```

Comment: why are you trying to achieve this with a shortcode?  Why not simply add your code in a javascript file and upload it on your page to execute when your dropdown changes?